# What is the proper way to handle a status led when HardFault_Handler or any error is raised?

Tags: stm32, c, error

I am trying to implement a very basic status indicator using an STM32 - Basically I would like to toggle a RED LED when a fault is triggered by the MCU.

Naively I added a toggle LED function in the while loop of the `HardFault_Handler` function but it only run the while loop one cycle.

Where should I implement such indicator?, is the function `HardFault_Handler` the correct one?

```
void HardFault_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN HardFault_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED_STATUS_GPIO_Port, LED_STATUS_Pin);
    HAL_Delay (100);
    /* USER CODE END W1_HardFault_IRQn 0 */
  }
}
```

To simulate a fault I am doing a simple division by zero.

Comment: The answer to this isn't obvious - it has to be done on a case-to-case basis. How critical is the error, how critical is the application, what is the application's safe mode if any etc etc. Apart from that, it also very much depends on your watchdog setting. I think you need to add more details to make it possible to answer this.

Comment: @Lundin thanks - what is the handler that is the most generic - Is there one handler that catch all errors whatever it is ?

Comment: It might depend on which compiler or startup code you use. The CubeMX generated code has usually defined all handlers weakly to Default_Handler, but you can read the startup assembly file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper way, everything depends on the fault and how you want to indicate it.

The HAL_Delay works by looping until the tick variable has counted enough ticks, and the ticks are incremented in a timer interrupt, which won't run because the code is in a fault handler.

So the code will hang in the HAL_Delay forever.

If you want to keep track of time, then use a dummy for loop or a hardware timer from which you can read the tick count.

Comment: Thanks, indeed switching to a dummy loop does make my LED blink.